# I can't show the content on angular modal

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm weak with frontend, I need to do a service in angular and I have a problem:

I have a code snippet it works perfect at the beginning of the code

```
                <div *ngIf="currentPlan">
                    <ul>
                        <li jhiSupplierOptionList
                            *ngFor="let service of currentPlan.funeralServices"
                            [service]="service"
                            [listener]="optionsListener">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

[he shows me something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyQX8.png)

I need to display this same information on one side of a modal but only the titles appear, the data does not appear.

Modal code:

```
    <div class="modal-body" id="compare-modal">
        <mat-dialog-content style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-items: stretch;height: 80vh;">

            <div style="flex: 1;padding: 16px;">
                teste esquerda
            </div>

            <div style="width: 2px;background-color: #ccc;"></div>

            <div style="flex: 1;padding: 16px;">

                <div *ngIf="currentPlan">
                    <ul>
                        <li jhiSupplierOptionList
                            *ngFor="let service of currentPlan.funeralServices"
                            [service]="service"
                            [listener]="optionsListener">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </div>
        </mat-dialog-content>
```

Sorry for the poorly done css, I should have created the classes and put the styles in a different file but I'll leave it for another time.

Anyway, the result looks like this:
[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27O95.png)

Could someone let me know where I'm going wrong? Remembering that my knowledge with angular is practically zero

Comment: Share your code in Stackblitz, it is much more better for investigation.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjtm2y?file=src/main.ts